# How to check if a numpy array contain a list of numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy array with another arrays inside and I want to know how I can check if all the values of another numpy array (Or list) are the same of the first one.

```
array1 = np.array([[11,3,4,6,7,8,9,1,2], [6,7,2,1,9,5,3,4,8]])
array2 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

I tried to do it with the `array2 in np.sort(array1)` but it return True.

I want to obtain False in the first array of the array [11,3,4,6,7,8,9,1,2] because the number 5 is not in and True in the second one [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].
Thanks for taking your time to read it and trying to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are currently checking to see if any of the arrays match.

if you want False and True, you need an elementwise comparison. done via a list comprehension:

```
[all(array2 == arr) for arr in np.sort(array1)]
```

which gives `[False, True]`

the `all()` is there because just checking `array2 == arr` will give a list of True/False for each entry, but we want a full match

Comment: thanks!! that was exactly what I need.